# Fetch redis configuration values and view within a C# console program

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I want to know is there a way to fetch configuration data loads within redis-cli (using "config get *" command) and view them within a c# console program. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently done something similar, where I am capturing the INFO for several different stats types.  If you are using the StackExchange client, the IServer interface exposes a method called ConfigGet() that will allow you to ask for specific config settings by name (or in your case, maybe passing in "*").

Here is some sample code (sorry it's in VB, that is what I was using for this project)

```
Public Sub Demo
    Dim configurationString as String = "localhost:6379"
    Dim options As ConfigurationOptions = ConfigurationOptions.Parse(configurationString)
    options.AllowAdmin = true
    Dim mu As ConnectionMultiplexer = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(options)
    Dim server As IServer = mu.GetServer(configurationString)

    Dim configSettings as KeyValuePair(Of String, String)() = server.ConfigGet("*")
    For Each settingPair As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In configSettings
        Dim configurationKey as String = settingPair.Key
        Dim configurationSetting as String = settingPair.Value
        Console.WriteLine("Config {0} = {1}", configurationKey, configurationSetting)
    Next
End Sub
```